# Add a method on the x Button on JFrame and WordWrap

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jframe

So I'm Making a Notepad on Java GUI, I have a lot of problems at the time so please help me. My First problem as Stated on the title I want to add a method to the x button on JFrame. I have a method on the codes below but I don't know how to input it on the x button.

And my other problem is the word-wrap `JCheckBoxMenuItem`. It does not work I don't know why . I want it to behave just like in a ordinary notepad (if you click it it will word wrap and if you click it again it will stop).

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;
import javax.swing.text.DefaultEditorKit;

public class Sample extends JFrame implements ActionListener  {


    private JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea("", 0,0);// TextArea
    private JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar(); // menuBar item



    private JMenu edit =new JMenu("Edit"); // Edit menu
    private JMenu file = new JMenu("File"); // File menu
    private JMenu format = new JMenu ("Format");// Format Menu

//    private WordButtonHandler wordHandler;

    //In Format Menu.
    private JCheckBox Word=new JCheckBox("Word Wrap");
    private JMenuItem font=new JMenuItem("Font");


    // In the Edit menu.
    private JMenuItem cut=new JMenuItem(new DefaultEditorKit.CutAction());
    private JMenuItem copy=new JMenuItem(new DefaultEditorKit.CopyAction());
    private JMenuItem paste=new JMenuItem(new DefaultEditorKit.PasteAction());


    // In the File menu.
    private JMenuItem saveasFile=new JMenuItem("Save as");// a save-as option
    private JMenuItem newFile = new JMenuItem("New"); // a new option
    private JMenuItem printFile = new JMenuItem("Print");// a print option
    private JMenuItem openFile = new JMenuItem("Open");  // an open option
    private JMenuItem saveFile = new JMenuItem("Save"); // a save option
    private JMenuItem close = new JMenuItem("Close"); // and a close option!

    public Sample() {



        setSize(500, 300); 
        setTitle("Java Notepad"); 
        setDefaultCloseOperation(DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE); 
        textArea.setFont(new Font("Times New Roman", Font.BOLD, 12)); 
        textArea.setAutoscrolls(rootPaneCheckingEnabled);




        Container p = getContentPane();
        p.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        p.add(textArea);

        // menu bar 
        setJMenuBar(menuBar);

        menuBar.add(file); 
        menuBar.add(edit);
        menuBar.add(format);


       // Cut option.     
        cut.setLabel("Cut");
        cut.setAccelerator(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_X,ActionEvent.CTRL_MASK));
        edit.add(cut);

      // Copy option.
        copy.setLabel("Copy");
        copy.setAccelerator(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_C,ActionEvent.CTRL_MASK));
        edit.add(copy);

      // Paste option. 
        paste.setLabel("Paste");
        paste.setAccelerator(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_V,ActionEvent.CTRL_MASK));
        edit.add(paste);


        //Word Wrap Option
//       Word.addItemListener(wordHandler);
       format.add(Word);
//       wordHandler=new WordButtonHandler();

       // Font Option

       font.addActionListener(this);
       format.add(font);

        //New option     
       newFile.addActionListener(this);
       newFile.setAccelerator(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_N,ActionEvent.CTRL_MASK));
       file.add(newFile);





        // Open option
        openFile.addActionListener(this); // add an action listener (so we know when it's been clicked
        openFile.setAccelerator(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_O,ActionEvent.CTRL_MASK)); // set a keyboard shortcut
        file.add(openFile); // add it to the "File" menu



        //  Save option
        saveFile.addActionListener(this);
        saveFile.setAccelerator(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_S,ActionEvent.CTRL_MASK));
        file.add(saveFile);


        // Save as option.
        saveasFile.addActionListener(this);

        file.add(saveasFile);

         // Print option
        printFile.addActionListener(this);
        printFile.setAccelerator(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_P,ActionEvent.CTRL_MASK));
        file.add(printFile);


        //  Close option
        close.setAccelerator(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_F4,ActionEvent.CTRL_MASK));
        close.addActionListener(this);
        file.add(close);
    }
//    public class WordButtonHandler implements ItemListener{
//    
//      
//    @Override
//    public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e){
//        if(e.getSource()==Word){
//            if(e.getStateChange()==ItemEvent.SELECTED)
//                textArea.setLineWrap(true);
//                textArea.setWrapStyleWord(true);
//            if(e.getStateChange()==ItemEvent.DESELECTED)
//                textArea.setLineWrap(false);
//                textArea.setWrapStyleWord(false);
//        }
//    }
//    }



    public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e){
        if(textArea.getText().isEmpty() == false){
            JDialog.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true);
            int response = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Do you want to save changes ?","My Notepad",JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION, JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);

            if(response == JOptionPane.NO_OPTION){
                System.exit(0);
            }
            else if(response == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION){
                JFileChooser save = new JFileChooser(); 
                int option = save.showSaveDialog(this); 



            if (option == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {

                try {



                    BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(save.getSelectedFile().getPath()));

                    out.write(this.textArea.getText());

                    out.close(); 

                } catch (Exception ex) {

                    System.out.println(ex.getMessage());

                }

            }
            }    


        }
        else{
            System.exit(0);
        }   
    }


    @SuppressWarnings("empty-statement")
    public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e) {



        if (e.getSource() == this.close)
            dispose(); 


         if (e.getSource() == this.openFile) {
            JFileChooser open = new JFileChooser();
            int option = open.showOpenDialog(this); 
            File file ;
            if (option == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) 
                this.textArea.setText(""); 
                file=open.getSelectedFile();


            try{
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
            try{
            String line=in.readLine();
            while(line !=null){
                textArea.append(line+"\n");
                line=in.readLine();
            }              
            }catch(IOException ex){
                System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
            }             
               } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) { 

                  System.out.println(ex.getMessage());

                }

          }





        else if (e.getSource() == this.saveFile || e.getSource ()==this.saveasFile) {
            JFileChooser save = new JFileChooser(); 
            int option = save.showSaveDialog(this); 



            if (option == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {

                try {



                    BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(save.getSelectedFile().getPath()));

                    out.write(this.textArea.getText());

                    out.close(); 

                } catch (Exception ex) {

                    System.out.println(ex.getMessage());

                }

            }

        } else if(e.getSource()==this.printFile){
            try {
                 boolean complete = textArea.print();
                 if (complete) {
                         /* show a success message  */
                   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Success","Printing",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                         } else {
        /*show a message indicating that printing was cancelled */
                     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Cancelled","Printing",JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
                         }
                        } catch (Exception pe) {
             /* Printing failed, report to the user */
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Failed","Printing",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                }
        }


        else if (e.getSource()==this.newFile){

            if(textArea.getText().isEmpty() == false){
              //  textArea.setText("");
            JDialog.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true);
            int response = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Do you want to save changes ?","My Notepad",JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION, JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);

            if(response == JOptionPane.NO_OPTION){
                textArea.setText("");

            }
            else if(response == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION){
                JFileChooser save = new JFileChooser(); 
                int option = save.showSaveDialog(this); 



            if (option == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {

                try {



                    BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(save.getSelectedFile().getPath()));

                    out.write(this.textArea.getText());

                    out.close(); 
                    textArea.setText("");

                } catch (Exception ex) {

                    System.out.println(ex.getMessage());

                }

            }
            }    





        }   

        }

    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        Sample app = new Sample();

        app.setVisible(true);

}

}
```

How Can i make this block of code work. in my codes above? i can't seem to make it run

```
public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e){
    if(textArea.getText().isEmpty() == false){
        JDialog.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true);
        int response = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Do you want to save changes ?","My Notepad",JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION, JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);

        if(response == JOptionPane.NO_OPTION){
            System.exit(0);
        }
        else if(response == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION){
            JFileChooser save = new JFileChooser(); 
            int option = save.showSaveDialog(this); 



        if (option == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {

            try {



                BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(save.getSelectedFile().getPath()));

                out.write(this.textArea.getText());

                out.close(); 

            } catch (Exception ex) {

                System.out.println(ex.getMessage());

            }

        }
        }    


    }
    else{
        System.exit(0);
    }   
}
```

Comment: *"And my other problem is.."* ..best asked on a separate question, as SO is a Q&A Site, not a help desk.  After all, if someone knows the answer to one but not the other, should they answer?  Would they bother?

Comment: Other advice: 1) Use a logical and consistent form of indenting code lines and blocks.  The indentation is intended to make the flow of the code easier to follow! 2) A single blank line of white space in source code is all that is *ever* needed.  Blank lines after `{` or before `}` are also typically redundant. 3) Please learn common Java nomenclature (naming conventions - e.g. `EachWordUpperCaseClass`, `firstWordLowerCaseMethod()`, `firstWordLowerCaseAttribute` unless it is a `CONSTANT`) and use it consistently.

Answer (score 1):

> Add a method on the x Button on `JFrame`

Add a `WindowListener`.  See [How to Write Window Listeners](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/windowlistener.html) for details and examples.

Comment: how can i do that? sorry I'm just a newbie i don't know about that windowListener. Although i searched it still i cant understand it

Comment: *"how can i do that?"*  Are you looking at the original answer, or the edited one where I added a link to 'How to Write Window Listeners'?

Comment: I've tried everything i can , i still cant add a windowlistener .

Comment: Show us your attempt in the form of an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example) or [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example).  Tip: To keep it minimal, the example will not require either menus or components other than the frame itself.

Comment: I've tried adding windowListener but i think there's something wrong on my codes that it won't allow it.

Comment: ..where is the MCVE showing your attempt? *"..there's something wrong on my codes that it won't allow it."* What 'it'?  The IDE, the compiler, your cat..?  Always copy/paste error and exception output!